# How to draw a double-ended arrow between the numerator and denominator in a frac inside a sqrt, and an arrow labeled by an otimes pointing to that?

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, arrows

Here's what I have, and I've hand drawn what I seeking:

[image]

I'm after (a) a double-ended arrow with the two ends pointing to the numerator and denominator of a fraction under a square root, and (b) an arrow pointing to the double-ended arrow labeled by an `\otimes`.

I'm typesetting old lecture notes in LaTeX and need to be as accurate as possible, so this is what I need to do.  But it doesn't strike as straightforward.

I tried using `baseline` in `tikz`, but it didn't come out symmetric, and I wouldn't even know where to begin with the arrow pointing to the double-ended arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{\frac{N}{p(1-p)}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look for tikzmark

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A solution that uses `calc` to determine the position of the double arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[execute at begin node = $\displaystyle, execute at end node   = $]
        \node (eq) {\sqrt{\frac{N}{p(1-p)}}};
        \draw[<->] ($(eq.north east)!.3!(eq.south east)$) to[in=0, out=0,distance=10] node[right] {\leftarrow\otimes} ($(eq.north east)!.7!(eq.south east)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some adjustments to tailor it to your liking:

- For a longer arrow, change `\leftarrow` to `\longleftarrow`
- You can use colours by adding `\color{}`
- The size of the bend of the double arrow is in `distance=...`
- The vertical position of the arrowheads of the double arrow are the
  `!.3!` and `!.7!`
- The horizontal position of the arrowheads of the double arrow can be
  adjusted by adding `-(.4,0)`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[execute at begin node = $\displaystyle, execute at end node   = $]
        \node (eq) {\sqrt{\frac{N}{p(1-p)}}};
        \draw[<->,red] ($(eq.north east)!.3!(eq.south east)-(.4,0)$) to[in=0, out=0,distance=20] node[right] {\color{blue}\longleftarrow \color{green}\otimes} ($(eq.north east)!.7!(eq.south east)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remarkable!  Thanks for this (and thanks to the other answerer).

Answer (score 16):

Here is something that should get you started on using `tikzmark`:

[image]

### Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- There probably are easier ways to determine the locations.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node[baseline, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{\frac{N\mytikzmark{top}}{p(1-p)\mytikzmark{bottom}}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (Top Start)  at ([yshift=0.25\baselineskip]top -| bottom);
    \coordinate (Bottom End) at ([yshift=0.2\baselineskip]bottom);
    \draw [latex-latex, red, thick] 
            (Top Start) to[out=-5, in=5, distance=0.75cm] 
            (Bottom End);
    \node (MidHeight) at (Top Start |- Bottom End) {};
    \node  at ([shift={(1.5cm,0.5\baselineskip)}]Bottom End) (OTIMES) {$\otimes$};
    \draw [blue, -stealth, thick] (OTIMES) -- ++(-0.8cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: What a beautiful image!